# Which value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property should be used in production environment?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Which value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property should be used in production environment? Whether it should be create, update or create-drop????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** to **validate** in all your environments/profiles.

You might want to check **Liquibase** or **Flyway** to update your DB in running envs and for integration testing.